# Error : Weblogic Maven Plugin deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic-maven-plugin

i want to use weblogic-maven-plugin in my maven project in eclipse so i generated weblogic-maven-plugin.jar in weblogic server 12c 1.2.1 and i am using it.

```
    <plugin> 
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId> 
    <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>12.1.2.0</version> 
    <configuration>
        <adminurl>t3://weblogicServerIP:7001</adminurl>
        <user>weblogic</user> 
        <password>weblogic123</password> 
        <targets>Cluster-1</targets>
        <upload>true</upload> 
        <action>deploy</action> 
        <remote>true</remote> 
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source> 
        <name>myProject</name>
    </configuration> 
    <executions> 
        <execution> 
            <phase>install</phase> 
            <goals> 
                <goal>deploy</goal> 
            </goals>
        </execution> 
    </executions> 
</plugin>
```

But i have a problem about weblogic maven plugin. if i built my maven project in my local to deploy, built is failed;

> 

```
The args for the deployer is: -noexit -adminurl t3://weblogicServerIP:7001 -user weblogic -password ******** -deploy -name myProject -source myProject.war -targets Cluster-1 -upload -remote -verbose 
weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -noexit -adminurl t3://weblogicServerIP:7001 -user weblogic -deploy -name myProject -source myProject.war -targets Cluster-1 -upload -remote -verbose
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:04.013s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 13 10:27:27 EET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/23M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:12.1.2.0:deploy (default) on project myProject: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 't3://weblogicServerIP:7001': weblogic.security.utils.KeyStoreConfiguration. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server.
```

i enabled tunneling of server protocol but there is nothing to change in this error.
By the way i run this cmd which is below in weblogicServer cmd line, i didn't get error message. Finally my deployment was succeed.

```
java weblogic.Deployer -noexit -adminurl t3://weblogicServerIP:7001 -user weblogic -password weblogic123 -deploy -name myProject -source myProject.war -targets Cluster-1 -upload -verbose -debug
```

By the way i extracted weblogic-maven-plugin.jar and i didn't find KeyStoreConfiguration.java. i didn't find anywhere.

So what should i do? is there a newtwork problem or weblogic-maven-plugin.jar is faulty?

Could you help me?

Comment: having the same error here, any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the class **weblogic.security.utils.KeyStoreConfiguration** is required by the plugin but is not found on the classpath.

You can add the relevant jar file to the classpath like so

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <adminurl>t3://${deploymentServer}:${deploymentServerPort}</adminurl>

                <user>${deploymentUsername}</user>
                <password>${deploymentPassword}</password>

                <debug>true</debug>
                <upload>true</upload>
                <action>deploy</action>
                <remote>false</remote>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
                <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
                    <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

See these [instructiions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24378/jarbuilder.htm#SACLT239) for generating the wlfullclient jar